# Function to count the number of primes between two numbers

Tags: c++

I'm trying to count the number of prime numbers between two numbers and my program is running fine but it's printing out the answer plus 1. I'm not exactly sure what's wrong with my prime number checker. I'm getting 26 instead of 25 when checking between 1-100.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int number_of_primes(int from, int to){

    int count=0;
    for (int a=from ; a < to ; a++)
    {
        bool prime = true;
        for (int c=2 ; c*c <= a ; c++)
        {
            if(a % c == 0)
            {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
         }
        if(prime) count++;
    }


return count;

}

int main(){

int a=1;
int b=100;

cout<<number_of_primes(a, b)<<endl;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You could have printed out each entry you got as prime, and then compared the list you got to nearly any search result for *"how many prime numbers between 1 and 100"* (most of the hits include the list), to see what you were counting that you should not.  :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're including `1` in the count, just skip it:

```
int number_of_primes(int from, int to) {

    int count = 0;
    for (int a = from; a < to; a++)
    {
        if (a == 1)
            continue; // Skip 1
        ...
```

Otherwise, as Mark suggested, you might as well do:

```
a = max(from, 2) // Disallow 1/0 values
```

The rest of the code is correct.

Comment: thanks, I haven't gone over continue so there was no way I would've known that but Marks way works fine also.

Comment: @user3371154 `continue` is just saying "ignore everything else on this block for this iteration".

Answer (score 2):

You're counting 1 as a prime, but it isn't.